# Bluetooth problem on Asus U32 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, bluetooth, asus

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Asus U32 alongside Windows 8. Recently I've upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and since then the Bluetooth is not working anymore. Whenever I try to turn it on from the settings it just go back off seconds after I turned it on. I've tryed with the rfkill command and it says that the Bluetooth device is not blocked (both soft and hard).

I have no idea what is wrong and how to solve this issue.